# Cannot set wallpaper on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

A few months ago, I attempted to set my wallpaper only to have the wallpaper become a black screen.

Since then, whenever I try to set my wallpaper, the personalization settings are toggled to "Solid Color" immediately, rendering me unable to set a wallpaper. This happens if I attempt to manually select "Picture".

That being said, Windows will allow me to manually do it SOMETIMES. However, it usually only works with stock windows images and resets upon a few logins to a solid color.

I have run SFC and DISM in an attempt to fix it, to no avail. I have also attempted to test this on another user, and can confirm that it works completely fine on that user. So this should be a user profile issue.

I contacted Windows support with my findings, who suggested I manually create a new user and transfer all of my stuff over to it, which seems like a hack fix to me and I would really rather not do it.

How can I figure out what is wrong and/or fix it?

Comment: Hoenstly the Microsoft's suggestion is sound and sane. Trying to find out which one of the million things that can be wrong/corrupt in one user's profile is the exact opposite.

Comment: Edit your question to indicate what method you used to set the wallpaper

Comment: @Ramhound The method is irrelevant as I have tried all of them

Comment: Your profile is probably probably corrupt. Creating a new one will be the easiest and fastest fix. There are some things not worth trying to fix.  It will take only a few minutes to create a new profile and copy data, but you could spend countless hours trying to fix it and get nowhere.

Comment: @Laif - The method you used, “I attempted to set my wallpaper only to have the wallpaper become a black screen.”, absolutely is relevant.

Comment: @Ramhound I did that months ago, I don't remember what the exact method was. It was likely right click -> set

Comment: @Keltari The reason I want to avoid it is that it doesn't sound easy really at all, due to things like my editor preferences and user installed programs.